# Wrong output using random VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm writing a program for my vba class, it's almost complete but i'm running into one small problem. The program is supposed to ask a random multiplication question then the user hits submit to check weather the are right or wrong. All that works fine, however the answer to to the first question is the answer to all of them, even when the user hits next for the next question. Example, 1st question could be 6 *3 and the user enters 21 and it will say correct. The next question will come up say 3 * 2. If the user enters 6 it will say wrong, but if 21 is entered again its correct. I'm sure I am missing some really simple, but its driving me crazy and i'm pretty new to this. Any help is much appreciated!!Sorry if any of this is confusing.

```
Public Class MultiplicationTeacherForm
    Dim randomObject As New Random
    Dim one As Integer = randomObject.Next(1, 10)
    Dim two As Integer = randomObject.Next(1, 10)

Private Sub nextButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles nextButton.Click

    Dim one As Integer = randomObject.Next(1, 10)
    Dim two As Integer = randomObject.Next(1, 10)
    question.Text = ("How much is " & one & " times " & two)

End Sub

Private Sub submitButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles submit.Click

    Dim three As Integer = randomObject.Next(1, 3)
    Dim ans As Integer = one * two
    Dim correct As String = answer.Text
    Dim x As Integer = Convert.ToInt16(correct)

    If (three = 1) And (ans = x) Then
        response.Text = "Very Good!"
    ElseIf (three = 2) And (ans = x) Then
        response.Text = "Excellent!"
    ElseIf (three = 3) And (ans = x) Then
        response.Text = "Great Job!"
    Else
        response.Text = "No, Please try again."
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub MultiplicationTeacherForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    question.Text = ("How much is " & one & " times " & two)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `nextButton_Click` isn't updating the `one` and `two` variables of your form, but rather creating new locals that are shadowing the form's. Just do:

```
one = randomObject.Next(1, 10)
two = randomObject.Next(1, 10)
```

instead of the first two lines you already have.

Comment: Don't forget to mark "correct" answers as such in stack overflow. You'll get a green checkbox by my answer once you do.

Comment: @BrandanBassett - By the way, 3 * 6 is 18 not 21!  :P